# Find a solution to the ODE?

Tags: differential

$dy/dx = x\cos2x/3y^2$
So far I've rearranged.

$dy3y^2 = x\cos2x dx$

Then do I just solve for $y$?
If so how do I do that? I'm just a little confused on the next steps.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You integrate both sides

Comment: I gave you a hint (answer) down below. Make sure you vote up and approve it if it answered your question, so that the thread goes down as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we write it as : $y'(x) = \frac{xcos(2x)}{y^(x)} $

Hint : First **multiply** both sides with : $3y^2(x)$ and then integrate both sides with respect to x. You will then find $y(x)$.

Comment: After doing that i got $y^3 = 1/3 x^3cos(2) +C$  i feel that is wrong

Comment: You integrated wrong. The answer is : $y^3(x) = \frac{1}{4}\cos(2x) + \frac{1}{2}x\sin(2x) + c$

Comment: Please, be careful and integrate correctly, that's an easy integral to evaluate.

Comment: Oh i see what i did! then all i do is take cube root of other side?

Comment: Yes, but you need to detect 3 different cases, depending on the value of the "thing" under the cubic root.

Comment: Fillippatos so say if i had an initial condtion of $y(0)=0$ and i had to find $y(\pi)$ how would i do that, i tried and got 3cube root $\pi$

Comment: You just plug $ x=0$ and find $c$ and then plug $x=π$ and find the value. I don't know, I won't do arithmetic calculations now, you can do that with a calculator in 1 second.